# How do I find out why "a question here fails to meet quality standards"?

Tags: discussion

I had a valid question about normal distributions in higher dimensions to ask here.
But I can't -- it "does not meet our quality standards". I can't find any reference to what these standards might be.

And here I'm asking a question that is general and site-specific, and does not belong solely with the tag I'm using. I can't create a tag like "site-specific" because I'm too much the newbie. Sigh.

Comment: Welcome to CrossValidated, omatai!  This question should be asked on meta, not on the main site.  Click on "meta" at the top of the page, and ask there.

Comment: [FAQ](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq) may also be useful.

Answer (score 4):

Don't blame the bot doing this -- he is only a mindless computer trying to fend off spammers.

Here is a [canonical answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards) to this problem -- in short, try to make the title represent the question topic, use proper capitalization, write in English and make it longer than one line.

Comment: Thanks... although as the comments on that page suggest, it would at least be useful to make a link from the error message to where you can get information on what the error might mean.